# How to declare array inside array in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I'm not sure, is this the best practice to declare 2D array?. If not,please suggest me the possible solution.Thank you.

```
@interface RAGamePlayScene ()
@property (strong)NSArray *twoSetArray;
@end

@implementation RAGamePlayScene
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
self.twoSetArray=@[@[@1, @8, @12],@[@8,@12,@3],@[@1,@7,@11],@[@7,@11,@5],@[@5,@10,@9],@[@10,@9,@3],@[@6,@7,@8],@[@7,@8,@2],@[@6,@11,@10],@[@11,@10,@4],@[@2,@12,@9],@[@12,@9,@4]];
}
@end
```

Comment: Are those numbers important or are they simply placeholders? Also, make sure to declare your variables (nonatomic).

Comment: Those numbers are fixed and can't be changed. Thanks.

Comment: I would put each subarray on a separate line for readability, but otherwise it's fine.

Comment: I cannot stand the "readability" argument anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is a clean(-ish) interface, you could probably go with something like that:

```
@interface TwoDimensionalArray : NSObject

- (instancetype)initWithRows:(NSArray *)rows;

- (NSArray *)objectAtIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)index;

@end
```

You'd have a necessary check for row length equality in the initializer, and that's about it. Element access is as simple as that: `array[1][2]`.